# WooCommerce - Custom related product (Spareparts)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I’ve googled for ages but I’m stuck.

I want to add a link between products and spare parts. For example: The product (A laptop) and the spare part (an adapter) and (a battery).

The spare parts fit to several products.

What is the best way to create and display such a link?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best way in this case is to set up **cross-sells**. On the product edit page, got to `Product Data > Linked Products`. Add some products, then update the product.

Depending on your theme, cross-sells will be shown on the cart or the single product page (or both). If not, there are a bunch of plugins available, or you could display them in your template by hand .

Comment: Thank you! I've now added them as Cross-sells but I can not find a way of showing the cross-sells on the single-page. I think I've tried every single code snipped out there with no luck. Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can try this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-cross-sell-products-display/